# How to compact hard-coding into arrays and for loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have written a function to display some pictures on my site:

```
function draw_things(){

    var thingArray = new Array(10);

    thingArray[0] = {
        thingTitle : "First Thing",
        thingComments : "Random Words",
        thingSRC : "folder/0.jpg",
        thingHREF : "#",
        thingRating : '0',
        thingDimensions: '644'
    }

    thingArray[1] = {
        thingTitle : "Second Thing",
        thingComments : "Random Words",
        thingSRC : "folder/1.jpg",
        thingHREF : "#",
        thingRating : '0',
        thingDimensions: '644'
    }

}
```

I hard-coded the above code with 10 elements.

However, I am trying to condense into smaller code using a for loop like so:

```
function draw_things(){

var thingArray = new Array(10);
var title = ["First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth", "Sixth", "Seventh", "Eighth", "Nineth", "Tenth"];
var str = "folder/";
var toStr;
var thingSRCStr;
var thingTitleStr;

for (var i = 0; i < thingArray.length; i++)
{
    toStr = i.toString();
    thingStr = str + toStr + ".jpg";
    thingTitleStr = title[i] + " Thing";

    thingArray[i] = {
        thingTitle : thingTitleStr,
        thingComments : "Random Words",
        thingSRC : memeStr,
        thingHREF : "#",
        thingRating : '3',
        thingDimensions : '644'
    }
}
```

The problem is, some of those images are .gif files. For example, 1.gif and 6.gif while the others are all .jpg.

How would go about combating this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Use an array for the image names like you did for `title`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create an array of files that have gif extension. And then used it to choose between `.jpg` and `.gif`

```
...
var gifs = [1, 6];
...
for (var i = 0; i < thingArray.length; i++)
{
    ...
    thingStr = str + toStr + (gifs.indexOf(i) != -1 ? ".gif" : ".jpg");
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is wrong :D  You should take 'jpg' if indexOf == -1

Answer (score 2):

Just build an array containing indexes of the items with `gif` images:

```
var gifIndexes = [1, 6];
```

Then

```
thingStr = str + toStr + "." + (gifIndexes.indexOf(i) >= 0 ? "gif" : "jpg");
```